# Mockito verify says arguments aren't the same?

Tags: java, csv, mockito, apache-commons

I have a test that returns a list of CSVRecords (from Apache Commons) using this method:

```
public static List<CSVRecord> returnRecords(File file) throws IOException {

        Reader reader = new FileReader(file);

        return CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(reader).getRecords();
    }
```

However, when I use this in my tests like so:

```
    import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;



public class testClass {  

     @Mock
        private Persistence persistence;

    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        service = new Service(persistence);
    }


     @Test
        public void getIdsByUsersReturnsMostRecentIds()
            throws IOException {
    
        List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = returnRecords(new File("csv"));
    
        when(service.getIds(csvRecords)).thenReturn(expectedResult);
    
        verify(persistence).getIds(csvRecords);
    
    }

}
```

The mockito verify fails saying that the arguments are different.  They are literally the exact same.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There is not enough details to reproduce your error. Please add a complete example of failing test including mocks etc...

Comment: @pirho thanks, I've added more details